# Converting an org-mode table to LaTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, org-table

IS there a way to 'texify' an ASCII table written with Emacs' orgtabl-mode. Creating tables in this mode is extremely simple.

E.g. suppose I have this table

```
|------+-----+-----|
|    A |   B |   C |
|------+-----+-----|
| 2.34 | 2.7 | 8.9 |
| 3.67 | 4.5 | 8.9 |
|------+-----+-----|
```

If in EMACS, I could highlight this region and do soething like `M-x texify` or whatver to generate the latex code for that table that would save me a lot of pain.

Any non-emacs suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: Is the table in question too large to convert it to the LaTeX `tabular` environment manually?

Comment: Yes. But even for small tables if such a functionality is possible that would be helpful. Making tables in latex is such drudgery. :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use orgtbl-mode. In your latex buffer, do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`orgtbl-mode`, add

```
% BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL thenameofthetable
% END RECEIVE ORGTBL thenameofthetable
```

where you want the table to be.

add

```
#+ORGTBL: SEND thenameofthetable orgtbl-to-latex :splice nil :skip 0
|------+-----+-----|
|    A |   B |   C |
|------+-----+-----|
| 2.34 | 2.7 | 8.9 |
| 3.67 | 4.5 | 8.9 |
|------+-----+-----|
```

after the \end{document}

and do <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> on the org-mode table

The other solution is already given by Michael Hoffman: use org-mode export capability with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

Comment: How can I get vertical lines using your method?

Comment: you should use :splice t, and specify yourself your "\begin{array}", and "\end{array}"

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> should do it.

Comment: This won't work for orgtbl-mode tables, since they aren't in their own org-buffer.  Rémi's suggestion is how you include orgtble into a latex document.

Answer (score 0):

In org-mode, put your cursor in the table, and `M-x org-table-export` exports the table in a file.